# How to properly replace sprintf with << operator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf, cout

Original line: `sprintf(buffer, "section%d rows", x + 1);`

My line: `buffer << "section" << (x + 1) << " rows";`

The compiler complains,

> expression must have integral or enum type.

Consider the following declaration if need be?

```
char buffer[SIZE]; // SIZE is 128, here is the buffer I want to read into
```

update: x is an integer!

Comment: You need a `stringstream`.

Comment: You need an `ostringstream` from `<sstream>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

char [] doesn't have a << operator that works they way you are looking for.  Try using the stringstream or another stream class.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/

Comment: aah, I see. I will accept your answer when SO lets me.

Comment: is there a way to do this with cin?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What do you want to do with cin?

Comment: Maybe just a short description will help you.  cin and cout are specific examples of streams.  Streams are a type of object that let you "stream" data by reading/writing data from/to it a piece at a time.  Often they use the >> and << operators to do this reading and writing.  cin and cout are streams provided to read/write to the standing input/output.  fstreams are used to read/write from files.  stringstream can be used to read/write from strings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring> // for memcpy

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "test: " << 10 << " !";
    char buf[128];
    memcpy(buf, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().size() + 1); // to include '\0'
    cout << buf << endl;
}
```

Here you need to use `memcpy` to copy into the buffer.

Comment: `const char* buf = ss.str().c_str();` creates a dangling pointer.